# Blender crashes with GPU installed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, windows, hardware

On a recently assembled computer, attempting to run the BMW Benchmark using CPU render causes the screen to flickers after a few minutes and blender crashes, while using GPU render works fine. After removing the GPU and installing Intel Integrated Graphics drivers, the CPU render completes normally. I think that it could be the Nvidia driver version 398.82 which is causing the issue. Does blender recommend a specific driver to use?

Specifications:

i7 8700K stock speed

Gigabyte GTX 1080 Ti

Windows 10

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Same problem here. The solution is simple, just reinstall windows. I use i7 6700K, Gigabyte 1080ti (aorus extreme edition), after reinstall everything works fine, with all the fresh drivers.

Comment: That's a little extreme. Generally a graphics driver re-install is enough. OP should try that first. Windows 10 is notorious for having issues with all kinds of software unfortunately.

Comment: I would hardly call it a "simple solution." Bit drastic. That's like getting a new phone because you lost a call.

Comment: This should not be marked as an answer. There is simply no need to "reinstall Windows" whenever you run into a simple problem. It never was and it never will be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you had internal GPU and dedicated GPU then something is wrong while detecting the GPU.
Disabling and re-enabling the dedicated GPU would solve the issue.

I hope this helps you